# How do I put these on the same line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's a stupid question, I'll give you that. For the life of me I can't figure out how to align the text and my colorpicker. How do I get everything to be on one line, rather than the two lines it is now. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/3/). I've tried getting rid of display:block and clear:both but that didn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="http://evoluteur.github.com/colorpicker/css/evol.colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="http://evoluteur.github.com/colorpicker/js/evol.colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color_picker").colorpicker();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Select a color: <input id="color_picker" value="#92cddc"/></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see my fiddle for the css and js (I don't want to clutter everything up by posting everything here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try using this way: http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/6/

### html:

```
<span style='display:block; width:320px;'>
  Select a color: <input id="color_picker" value="#92cddc"/>
</span>
```

### jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color_picker").colorpicker();
    $("#color_picker").parent().css('float','right');
});
```

Although i suggest you to do it with `css`.

What happened there:

When you bind the colorpicker to the input element `jQuery wraps it with div` so if you don't style that div it `will always be in the second line` and `i styled it dynamically with use of jQuery`, using `.parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
$("span > div").css("display","inline-block");
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/C7hAY/12/

Comment: This is not scalable as this will set style for all divs inside a span.

Comment: @ATOzTOA of course I just based on OP fiddle, I think he know to put a specific id or class for that span to make it unique. I don't think it's deserve to receive a downvote though

Answer (score -1):

**The issue:**

When you create the color picker, it wraps your `<input>` element inside a `div`. The generated code will look like this:

```
<span>Select a color: 
    <div style="width:181px;">
        <input id="color_picker" value="#92cddc" class="colorPicker evo-cp0">
        <div class="evo-colorind" style="background-color:#92cddc"></div>
    </div>
</span>
```

That's why there is a newline in there.

**Solution:** [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eUeey/)

Just set the style of the `div` to `display:inline-block;`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color_picker").colorpicker();

    $("#color_picker").parent().css("display", "inline-block");
});
```